# customtkinter - is there a way to perform validation on ComboBoxes?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

You can use validate and validatecommand on Entry widgets but you can't perform them on comboboxes.
Is there anyway to do so?

```
self.ESubject = ctk.CTkComboBox(
                self,
                values =  ["option1", "option2"],
                **_entry_options
            )
            self.ESubject.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "ew")
            self.ESubject.configure(validate = "key", validatecommand = (string_reg, '%P'))
```

Using this raises an error that states that 'validate' and 'validatecommand' are unsupported args. What can I do?

Comment: What do you want to *validate* on a combobox?

Comment: I want to validate the entry part of the combo box. string_reg() only accepts string characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the *internal entry widget* instead:

```py
self.ESubject._entry.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=(string_reg, '%P'))
```